# jQuery nth-child relative to previous selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do some pagination, and the following code assigns a class for each div saying which page it should go on:

```
        var numOfPages = Math.ceil($(".mods-flex-items > div:visible").length / 20);
        console.log(numOfPages);
        $("div[class*='onpage']").removeClass("onpage-1 onpage-2 onpage-3 onpage-4 onpage-5 onpage-6 onpage-7 onpage-8 onpage-9 onpage-10");
        for (i=1; i <= numOfPages; i++) {
            for (j=1; j <= 20; j++) {
                let num = (i-1)*20+j;
                console.log(num);
                $(".mods-flex-items > div:visible:nth-child("+num+")").addClass('onpage-'+i);
            };
```

However, there is an issue where it comes to the `:visible:nth-child` section on the bottom line. Because of the fact that this is coming after some categorisation, I want to apply the onpage-X class to only the visible elements. In jQuery, nth-child is relative to all children rather than to the previous selector so is there any way that I can make it the nth-child of the visible elements? ie if I had:

```
<div style="display:none"</div>
<div id='a'></div>
<div id='b'></div>
```

I would want div:visible:nth-child(2) to be div#b.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to merge everything into just one selector is not a great idea.

Ideally you should be using the `.each` function ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each)) and then calling the addClass on the result of `.find('div:visible').eq(1)` on the element from `.each`.

Example:

```js
$('.mods-flex-items').each(() => {
    $(this).find('div:visible').eq(1).addClass('xyz');
});
```

Comment: Hi Matt, the deprecated eq() selector has not changed anything. I'll try using each now. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't notice it's deprecated, let me update my answer. I believe your problem lies with the attempt to combine all the operations into one selector.

Comment: Nah, the problem is that nth-child is relative to all children not the previous selector. ie it will include the non-visible elements in its selection. For me, this means that, for example, nth-child(1) can be a `display:none` element which won't work. I need it to only be the first visible element.

Comment: Struggling to understand how I could use the $.each() function in this case, please can you elaborate?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/ is the one I intended, not $.each(). Basically you can use that to iterate over the results of a selector `$('selector').each(() => ...)`

Comment: I have made a mistake when it comes to .each, I've updated my answer.

Comment: This is selecting .mods-flex-items and not its children

Comment: You need to select the children inside of that function, manually. If you need an index you could substitute `() =>` for `(index) =>`.

Comment: To be honest I'm struggling so much to try and get this to work that it's working worse than the last time. I cannot get it to add any classes to the elements. it must be remembered that this is in a for loop so each wouldn't even make sense here.